# Choose an interval where the number $\left(\frac {2^{10}} {11}\right)^{11}$ is situated.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> The number
>
> $$\left(\frac {2^{10}} {11}\right)^{11}$$
> is
>
> $(A)$ strictly larger than  ${10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2} {10 \choose 5}$.
>
> $(B)$ strictly larger than ${10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2}$ but strictly smaller than ${10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2} {10 \choose 5}$.
>
> $(C)$ less than or equal to ${10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2}$.
>
> $(D)$ equal to ${10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2} {10 \choose 5}$.
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

**My attempt** $:$

Since $2^4 > 11$ so we have $\left(\frac {2^{10}} {11}\right)> 2^{6}$ $\implies$ $\left(\frac {2^{10}} {11}\right)^{11}>(2^{6})^{11}$.

Now $(2^{6})^{11}=(2^{6})^{10}.2^{6}=(2^{10})^{6}.2^{6}=(2^{10})^{4}.2^{26}>{10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2}.2^{26}$.Now we will show that $2^{26}>{10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2}{10 \choose 5}$.

Now $2^{7}>100={10 \choose 1}^{2},2^{11}>2025={10 \choose 2}^{2}$ and $2^{8}>252={10 \choose 5}$.This shows that $2^{26}>{10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2}{10 \choose 5}$. i.e. we have $(2^{6})^{11}>{10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2} {10 \choose 5}$ and consequently $\left(\frac {2^{10}} {11}\right)^{11}>{10 \choose 1}^{2} {10 \choose 2}^{2} {10 \choose 3}^{2} {10 \choose 4}^{2} {10 \choose 5}$.Hence $(A)$ is the correct option.

Now my question is :

Is there alternative easy way to determine the above option?Because at last the calculation becomes too much laborious and boring.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use $\log$ to compute faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}^2\binom{n}{3}^3\cdots \binom{n}{n}^n \leq \left(\frac{2^n}{n+1}\right)^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686904/how-to-prove-that-binomn1-binomn22-binomn33-cdots-binomnnn)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint $$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k} = 2^{10}$$

You can proceed with the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality.

Comment: Very nice idea!

Comment: what a trick ...